# Can any national European company do business in all other member states?

Tags: european-union, limited-liability-company

For example, could a limited liability company registered in a Baltic EU state offer services in Poland?

What I learn from the first comment to this question, this might depend for example on services nature.

So these should be online subscription services. But where to read such things, are these national regulation laws defining which companies types from what countries allow to do what?

Comment: In general, EU law provides for "free movement of services," but the details are fairly complicated.  The specific nature of the services is relevant, for example.  Perhaps a more detailed question would lead to a more focused -- and more useful -- answer.

Comment: The EU single market means that companies can do business in all member states, but that doesn't you could ignore the rules in those states. It just means you're no worse off than founding a company directly in that country. For laws originating from EU directives, the country of origin principle applies so you'd only have to consider the rules in your home country. However, a lot of rules are down to national laws. Whether this matters depends on the nature of your subscription service.

Comment: this is actually a helpful answer, @amon - thx!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. A company from one member state may do business in any E.U. state so long as it complies with local law in the course of doing so.

For example, a Dutch company doing business in Germany must still pay German taxes and comply with German labor laws for its German employees. But, it doesn't have to form a German subsidiary to do business in Germany.